# I need to find out which SQL columns do not match

Tags: sql-server

OK this seems to be a little complicated and confusing.

I have a base table

```
Schedule
(
    RowID, 
    ScheduleName, 
    ScheduleColumn1, 
    ScheduleColumn2, 
    ScheduleColumn3
)
```

I have a separate application that imports records to another table

```
ImportSchedule
(
    RowID, 
    ScheduleName,
    ScheduleColumn1, 
    ScheduleColumn2,  
    ScheduleColumn3 
)
```

Now I need to join the 2 tables and display records that do no match. Basically if table `ImportSchedules` does not have matching records on columns `ScheduleColumn1`, `ScheduleColumn2`, `ScheduleColumn3` with table `Schedule`.

This is easy with the help of left join on all the above three columns.

The difficult part is finding which column does not match and list it as a failure reason.

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that data? It would make it easier for us to understand your question and attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a CASE ... WHEN for each column (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
 SELECT
      CASE 
          WHEN A.ScheduleColumn1 = B.ScheduleColumn1 THEN 'EQUAL'
          WHEN A.ScheduleColumn1 IS NULL AND B.ScheduleColumn1 IS NULL THEN 'EQUAL'
          ELSE 'NOT EQUAL' 
      END AS ScheduleColumn1Comparison,
      -- for other columns
      -- your join
```

---

You'd get one comparison column for each of your columns that indicates if the values are equal. If you want a single column you could use the same logic to concatenate which columns differ, like so

```
SELECT
  LTRIM(RTRIM(
    CASE 
        WHEN A.ScheduleColumn1 = B.ScheduleColumn1 THEN ''
        WHEN A.ScheduleColumn1 IS NULL AND B.ScheduleColumn1 IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE 'ScheduleColumn1' END 
    + ' ' +
    CASE 
        WHEN A.ScheduleColumn2 = B.ScheduleColumn2 THEN ''
        WHEN A.ScheduleColumn2 IS NULL AND B.ScheduleColumn2 IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE 'ScheduleColumn2' END 
    + ' ' +
    --- other columns     
  )) AS Comparison
  -- your join
```

Answer (score 1):

We use data compare tool (like [this one](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/) or [another](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) from red gate). It gives full information about data difference: missing rows in both tables, changed rows.

[image: red gate data compare]